# Mongoid: Setting "asdf" as a date field's value, it is automatically replaced with "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, date, mongoid

I noticed that when I set `"asdf"` as a Mongoid date field, then it is automatically replaced with `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` **before** any validation happens! So it is impossible to check for the correct format of the input, because when the input has an incorrect format, Mongoid automatically replaces it with `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`.

Is this a known problem? I'm in a hurry right now, if you need more code examples, I will provide it tomorrow.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is described here: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2950

There is a solution here: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/pull/2465

If the name of your date field is "startdate" for example, you can add the following method to validate:

```
validate :startdate_valid_format

def startdate_valid_format
  begin
    Date.parse(startdate_before_type_cast)
  rescue
    errors.add(:startdate, "is formatted incorrectly")
  end
end
```